# word problem, semigroups, group, unclear formulation and picture

Tags: semigroups, word-problem

[Here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mkambites/events/nbsan/nbsan10_thomas.pdf), on page 4, what it means the r.h.s. of $W=$?

Also, on page 5 there, I do not understand the English in the sentence.
Can someone reformulate it, so that a foreign language speaker understands it?

Comment: The meaning is $\phi^{-1}(1)$. Meaning the set of all elements which map to the identity element under the map $\phi$.

Comment: What part of p5 do you not understand? There are several sentences.